# Calling AJAX is not working onclick of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling an API from AJAX,

When I am Calling AJAX like this,

```
$(function (){

    $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url :"/tournament",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           console.log('success',data);
       },
       error:function(exception){
           alert('Exception:'+exception);
       }   
   });

});
```

This is working fine without any errors but when I am using this..

```
$('#btnadad').on('click',function (){

   alert("ok");
   $.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   url :"/tournament",
   success: function(data) {
        console.log('success',data);

   },
   error:function(exception){
      alert('Exception:'+exception);
   }
}); 
});
```

This popups "error" alert,
can anybody help me whats the error?

HTML Body is Like this,

```
<form>
<h2>
    <font color="#FFFFFF">
    <br><br><input type="text" name="name" placeholder ="Tournament Name"><br>
    <table>
        <?PHP
        //print_r($teams);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name=<?php echo $taemId[$i] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $teamname[$i] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </table>
    <button id="btnadad">ADD</button>

</form>

<script src ="/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

here I am calling one API and Displaying the Checkboxes Dynamically.

I am checking The Console...when I am clicking button ,the alert box is popping up and in networks tab tournament path's status is cancelled .when I am clicking it on to see the response it shows fail to load response data.

I have Tried calling this function in same html file in  tag but it is also not working.

```
<script>
function getOnClick()
{
    alert("ok");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://harshal:8888/tournament",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("no error in alert");
            console.log('success', data);

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error in alert");
        }
    });
}
```

and calling it on button's onclick Event ut it also gives me the same result

Comment: And what's in your console and network tabs?

Comment: Have you tried to debug what the error is? The `error` handler takes several parameters containing details about the problem. There's also the console to check. The issue will be somewhere in your server side code.'Not working' is never enough information.

Comment: I have Something Like this Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://s0.spicmcjs.info/dealdo/shoppingjs4?b=Chy9mZaMDhnSptaMzgf0yt0Ln0iLmJ…S9jMLUC3rNCNa9jMLHzZ1JBgLLBNqXmdaUlIzJB29RAwvZu3rHDhvZpwnVB2TPzuvUywjSzwq=".

Comment: There has to be something else going on that you haven't disclosed that makes these different because the code is obviously identical.  The next piece of data to gather is the specific error information returned as arguments in the ajax error handler.

Comment: error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);} used this which gives me alert like "Exeption:[object Object]"

Comment: Do you seriously not understand that `[object Object]` is not helpful?

Comment: can you show your html that goes with it

Comment: Actually I have just started today I haven't work with the AJAX before

Comment: Have you taken the `$(function (){` out? your onClick should still be inside that

Comment: Onclick is inside that      $(function (){ };

Comment: Actually I want to call ADD API on onclick of that button using AJAX  .I was just calling API to get result not adding the form to check whether its working or not , but it didn't.

Comment: When you said, it worked with former code. What did you mean by it? ?Have you got success message on your console?

Comment: Add to the ajax

   dataType: 'json'

Comment: @Rahul Yes I got Success message on console ,the proper response from API.

Comment: #Raul I have tried it its still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks For the Help Friends,your Efforts matters a lot to me,I am feeling glad to tell you that I just found the answer for this the below code makes it happened ..

```
$('#btnadad').on('click',function (e){       
   alert("ok");
   $.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   url :"/tournament",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
        console.log('success',data);

   },
   error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
}); 
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$ajax error function takes 3 parameters.  [Jquery ajax error](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred.

try changing like this

```
$('#btnadad').on('click',function (){

   alert("ok");
   $.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   url :"/tournament",
   success: function(data) {
        console.log('success',data);

   },
   error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ){
      alert('Exception:'+errorThrown );
   }
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. If you use `onclick`, do not use a `form`. In local environment, it is working, but when you go to production, the `ajax` request is cancelling. The solution is removing the `form` tag and adding a `div` tag.